# Opamp stability given in not inverting configuration

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain, stability, inverting-amplifier

If a datasheet (like [AD828](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad828.pdf)) says that an opamp is stable at Gain >2 (or reccomends to work with G>2, hence it is clearly not unity gain stable), what can we deduct about its stability in the inverting configuration at G=-1; G=-2 or G<<-2 (like in any transimpedance amplifier configuration)?
Is it always instable in the three above cases if not compensated?

Comment: Good question. The dynamic performance is also specified at G= -1, so it would seem that it is also stable below -1, but im not sure.

Comment: @Linkyyy Are you sure that you do not mean: *so it would seem that it is also INstable at G = -1* The **loopgain** does not change for G = 1 vs G = -1. It is also the **loopgain** that determines (in)stability. G= -1 vs G = +1 only differs in the way where the **input signal** is applied.

Comment: *transimpedance amplifier configuration* I think that the transimpedance amplifier is a bad example here as the ones I know all apply the input (current) at the - input so basically they're all **inverting**. I think we should only consider voltage amplifiers instead as these can be inverting and non inverting.

Comment: It's a video amplifier so why are you even considering as a TIA?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: Well the bandwidth at -1 is substantially lower than what is given at G=+2, so it would seem that a negative configuration has some other effects.

Comment: @Linkyyy *the bandwidth at -1 is substantially lower than what is given at G=+2* You're comparing apples to pears. It is only fair to compare G = -1 vs G = 1 **or** G= 2 vs G = -2. The BW will be different between G = +/-1 and G=+/-2 because GBW product is constant.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: Yes ofcourse, so the the BW should be higher for lower gain, which it is not.

Answer (score 5):

Stability is a function of NOISE GAIN, not strictly the same thing as gain...

Noise gain follows the formula for the gain of a non inverting stage $$NG = 1 + Rf/Rg$$

For an inverting unity gain stage this will be 2, making the part stable in this configuration.

Comment: Although I've been an analog designer for 25 years, I didn't know about "noise gain" but looking up what it is, it is strongly related to **loop gain** which is what I use to evaluate loop stability. I like the term "noise gain" though as it emphasizes that there is no relation between stability and the input signal of the circuit. Good reading material: https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-033.pdf

Comment: The classics are by Tobey, Graeme, Huelsman; two good books

Comment: What is NG for a TIA? Infinite (Rg=0)?

Answer (score 0):

Loop gain is the stability determining factor.

Loop Gain = Beta * Ao  where Beta = feedback fraction = R1/(R1+R2) and Ao = open loop gain.

1/Beta = Noise Gain.

So a non inverting amplifier with a closed loop gain of 2 (R1=R2, Beta = 0.5 and Noise Gain=2) has the same Beta and therefore the same noise gain as an inverting amplifier with a closed loop gain of -1 (R1=R2, Beta = 0.5 and Noise Gain = 2).

This means that an inverting amplifier with a gain of -1 is as stable as a non-inverting amplifier with a gain of 2.

In addition to Noise Gain being the stability determining factor, Noise Gain also determines the bandwidth of an amplifier.

Bandwidth = GBW/Noise Gain.

So a non-inverting amplifier with a gain of 2 (R1=R2) has the same bandwidth as an inverting amplifier with a gain of -1 (R1=R2).
If you make the closed loop gains of the two amplifiers both equal to 2 then the inverting amplifier will have a bandwidth equal to 2/3 the bandwidth of the non-inverting amplifier.

Non-Inverting amplifier with a closed loop gain of 2 has R1=R2 and a noise gain of 2.
Inverting amplifier with a closed loop gain of 2 has R2=2*R1 and a noise gain of 3.

Comment: Take a look at the data sheet for the AD744 op amp which is stable for non-inverting gains of +2 or greater and also for inverting gains of -1 or greater. To be used as a unity gain follower this op amp requires extra compensation.

Answer (score -1):

Stabilty is a function of the total feedback phaseshift.

1) Rout + Cload: 100 ohms and 100pf are 10,000 picosecond time constant, producing 45 degrees phaseshift at 100 MegaRadians/second of 16MHz. Many opamps have Rout (internal output resistance) near 100 ohms; some have Rout >>> 1Kohms.

2) phase margin beyond 90 degrees: a 60 degree phase margin opamp (Unity Gain phase margin) has 90+30 = 120 degrees phase shift

3) phase shift at the virtual_ground node: assume 10pF on that node, and resistive equivalent (Rin || Rfb, or Rg || Rfb) of 1,000 ohms; this produces 10,000 picosecond tme constant, or 45 degrees at 16MHz.

What rescues a feedback network? Usually the parasitic feedback capacitance in parallel with the feedback resistor. IMHO